# A subcase of byzantine agreement (4 processes, the commander is a traitor)

Tags: algorithm, fault-tolerance

In case you don't know the problem, [see this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byzantine_fault_tolerance).

**Brief introduction:**

Processes communicate by reliable and timely messages. Traitors lie, also cheat on forwarding messages, they try to confuse loyals. Loyals try to agree on non-trivial actions (attack, retreat, only 2 actions). There is only one commander. If the commander is loyal and gives orders, loyals follow otherwise loyals agree on arbitrary actions.

**My problem**:

I don't understand this case: assume that there are 4 processes, only 1 process is commander, and the commander is a traitor. How can the system tolerate this? The commander can send 3 different messages to the 3 loyals. Each loyal forwards messages to the other 2 loyals. So each loyal will receive 3 different actions. How can the loyals decide to act uniformly?

The general result is: `3f + 1` processes needed to tolerate `f` traitors.

Comment: If you have 4 processes and one is a traitor, your general result at the end says that you can't tolerate it. You'd need at least 5 processes to handle a single traitor among them according to your formula. If the commander is a traitor, I'd think that's at least as bad.

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think the problem as described deals with a 2 state (attack / retreat), and your question describes a 3 state. That's why it "won't work" for you

Comment: hmm. I think you hit the critical point. Amit. then this question is closed

Comment: @Amit: Can you submit your comment as an answer so that we can vote it up and mark this question answered?

Comment: @CharlesStewart - added...

Comment: @JACKM - if you want to address someone in a comment, use an @ before their username so that they're notified of the comment

Answer (score 4):

The ***Byzantine fault tolerance*** problem deals with a scenario where 2 possible actions exist and must be agreed upon.

The problem described can't happen, because between 2 possible actions (2 "messages"), there can't exist "*3 different messages*".